# Android TabLayout with viewpager tab text color not working at first

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm using `TabLayout/ViewPager` and there are three fragments.

I set a default page of ViewPager with  `ViewPager.setCurrentItem()`. ViewPager shows me a fragment what i wanted to see but the tab's text color of TabLayout isn't applied properly.(First tab's text color is displayed as a selected tab at unconditionally at onCreate)

Can anyone please give me an advise about how can i fix this?

---

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    tabs.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a3000e"));
    tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#999999"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
mUnderlinePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize your TabLayout with your ViewPager:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Perform the setCurrentItem-operation after the setupWithViewPager-method was called.

Answer (score 0):

I updated android design support library and problem fixed.

`compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` in gradle